# Updating content provider values continuously

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

How to update a value in content provider continuosly?

Comment: this question is too vague and doesn't explain key information to allow people to answer your query

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) which can create periodic intents. You can listen to these intents using a Service or BroadcastReceiver which does the update during the intent receive.